# "line 3: syntax error near unexpected token" in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I am trying to run some executable with parameters several times. I wrote a script for it. But I am always getting an error and can't figure out on how to fix it.

```
#!/bin/bash

export VCF_FILE='KI_subsetted.recode.vcf'
for i in $(seq 22) do; /home/lab/Desktop/vcftools_0.1.13/bin/vcftools --vcf $VCF_FILE --chr i --out ./by_chrs_komi/i --recode; done
```

The error I am getting is:

```
./chrs.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `/home/lab/Desktop/vcftools_0.1.13/bin/vcftools'
./chrs.sh: line 3: `for i in $(seq 22) do; /home/lab/Desktop/vcftools_0.1.13/bin/vcftools --vcf ./KI_subsetted.recode.vcf --chr i --out ./by_chrs_komi/i --recode; done'
```

I am on the Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: you are saying `--chr i`, shouldn't it be `--chr "$i"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
for i in $(seq 22) ; do /home/aydar/Desktop/vcftools_0.1.13/bin/vcftools --vcf $VCF_FILE --chr $i --out ./by_chrs_komi/$i --recode; done
```

- semicolon (`;)` before do
- if `$i` is a number, no need for quotes.

or, programming style, and as per suggestion

```
for i in {1..22}
do 
  /home/aydar/Desktop/vcftools_0.1.13/bin/vcftools \
    --vcf $VCF_FILE --chr $i --out ./by_chrs_komi/$i --recode
done
```

Comment: or `for i in {1..22}`, even better

Comment: Thanks it worked. At least executable launches. However for some reason program cannot open the output file.

Comment: Error: Could not open VCF Output file: ./by_chrs_komi/22.recode.vcf

Comment: directory `by_chrs_komi` exists ? and is writable ?

Comment: yup. The directory exists

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 2 aydar aydar      4096 дек.  11 15:38 by_chr_komi 
It is the output of the ls -t command

Comment: is that by_chr**s**_komi  (with s) or by_chr_komi  (without) ?